# Как правильно обратиться к строке length у объекта в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь обратиться к строке length массива videoData1, при написании кода videoData1.dislikedBy.length, открывается ошибка [image: ошибка],
консоль выглядит так: [image: консоль объектов], подскажите как можно  правильно обратиться к свойству length.
(Сейчас часть кода выглядит так)

```
const { videoIdCC, isFetching, videoData1, userData } = useContext(WatchContext)
console.log(videoIdCC, isFetching, videoData1, userData,"длина лайков", videoData1.likedBy, "длина дизлайков", videoData1.dislikedBy.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Код1] (Пробовал двумя методами, ответ в консоли один и тот же)
Теперь код выглядит так[image: код]

Однако при попытки присваивания переменным консоль все равно выдает undefined
[image: Консоль]